# Raid Anaylsis Software

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid

Are there any great RAID analysis software tools out there?

Comment: You might want to expand your question to explain what you're looking to do. It's currently a bit short on detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is related to your other question about RAID, you probably are going to need to use whatever tools come with the raid hardware you're using. I can tell you that I like Dell's management tools, but as they only work with Dell servers it's no help to you if you have a HP or homebuilt server.

If you are using software RAID then the operating system's own disk management tools and logs keep track of status and so-on.

As David says, if this isn't what you're asking for then you need to expand your question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite RAID performance analysis tool for Microsoft Windows machines is SQLIO, a free utility from Microsoft.  I've written up a [SQLIO tutorial with a video](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SAN_Performance_Tuning_with_SQLIO) that explains how to get it, how to use it, and how to analyze the results.

If you're not after performance analysis, you can get better answers by telling us what you're trying to analyze (including the gear you're testing) and what operating system you're using.